# Rotating a view

Tags: java, android

I am making a library that accept Views as input.

I want to rotate those views... since they are a input, I cannot inherit from then to do a onDraw override...

So, how I rotate a view? (for example to display it at 23.589235 degrees)

If not possible to do it without overriding onDraw, there are a way in Java to achieve that effect without inheriting from View class?

EDIT: If possible, it would be nice if the solution worked on 1.5 (where I live 1.5 is still common)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

Let's try this again.

While the transformation methods are not available until API Level 11, the Animation API is available since Level 1. So I would suggest applying Animations with a duration of 0.

Original ridiculous, wrong answer:

You should really look at the methods available in View. setRotationX() and setRotationY() are among them, along with a bunch of other transformation methods.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: Dude, that is for 3.0... 3.0 devices don't even show up in the list of devices available because there are less 3.0 devices than 1.5 devices.

Comment: Huh, so it is. Apologies, I didn't click through to the full method definition to check the API level. I've edited the answer with a new approach I think will work.